# Maven project - load file from outside of resources folder (project root)

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a contacts application using Maven in Netbeans. For the operation of the program I want users to add and store images (contact avatars) in a folder /avatars and access them on a listener event. I can access images from within the ProjectRoot/src/main/resources/images directory, but cannot access ProjectRoot/avatars. *Note: I do not want to store avatars in the resources directory because these will be user-added during the programs operation.*

I have tried using getClass().getResource(avatarPath); as suggested in similar questions, but it has not worked. I have also tried adding the "avatars" directory to the POM as its own resource directory, but that has not worked either.

**How can I access files/folders in the root directory of my project when using Maven?**

```
listviewContacts.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Contact> observable, Contact oldValue, Contact newValue) {
            String avatar = newValue.getAvatar();
            String avatarPath = null;
            if (avatar.isEmpty()) {
                avatarPath = "/images/" + DEFAULT_AVATAR; // loads from ProjectRoot/src/main/resources/images
            } else {
                avatarPath = "/avatars/" + avatar; // won't load from ProjectRoot/avatars
            }
            try {
                imageviewContact.setImage(new Image(avatarPath));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                System.err.println("Could not locate " + avatarPath);
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in understanding where the different constructors of **javafx.scene.image.Image** begin their path.

When using the URL constructor for Image, the URL path will start in **Maven's defined resources folder** (/src/main/resources *or whatever additional resource directories were added to the pom.xml file*):

```
// the supplied string invokes the URL constructor
Image image = new Image("path/to/file");
```

When using the InputStream constructor for Image (via FileInputStream), the path will start at the **root directory** of the project/application:

```
// the FileInputStream invokes the InputStream constructor
Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("path/to/file"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 different things.

You can either have a **classpath resource** packed in jarfile along with your classes, or in a directory that is explicitly added java to java classpath(using java -cp commandline argument). That can be accessed via  getClass().getResource.

Or you can load a **file** from arbitrary location, using java.io.File. Then your "projectRoot" is some folder in a filesystem, that you can either hardcode, configure by -DprojectRoot=C:/fun/with/files, or use some of relative paths.
Maven has nothing to do with it, as avatars "will be will be user-added during the programs operation".

Your users will not launch your IDE, right ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I may indeed be misunderstanding something, but it does seem that Maven has something to do with it? I can access files within the resources directories, but not the project's root directory. For example, in the code provided the image loads when it is in the resources directory, but it will not load if I try to access it from the project root directory. This may or may not be a Maven configuration issue, but regardless I do not know why it will load from /src/main/resources/images but not from /avatars.

Comment: Maven will pack src/main/resources into your jarfile, therefore images will be available in getClass().getResource(). If you want maven to add some different folder into your jarfiles,then you can configure(https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) that in pom.xml.

Comment: Spelina, yes I have already tried all of that, I've already been to that link you provided before I posted. You can see in my original post "I have also tried adding the "avatars" directory to the POM as its own resource directory, but that has not worked either. " It did not work. This is why I asked the question. I understand Maven and the resources directory, as I tried to make clear in my original post. I do NOT want to pack the /avatars folder into the jar. It is a place that the application will save images to during runtime. Now you see my predicament; none of that is working...

Comment: Now compare your answer with mine:D. Also try to run your application out of your IDE and then check my answer again :